# Как сделать, чтобы гамбургер меню работало только на мобильных?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно, чтобы функция работала при ширине экрана ***`768px`*** и менее, а при большей - меню снова становилось обычным. Пробовала через условие `window.innerWidth < 769`, функция не срабатывает.
Подскажите, пожалуйста?

```js
$('.products-grid-header-item').on('click', function() {
  $('.products-grid-header-item').toggle();
  $('.products-grid-header li.active-items').removeClass('active-items');
  $(this).show();
  $(this).addClass('active-items');
});
```

```css
.products-grid-header li {
  display: flex;
}

.products-grid-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .products-grid-header {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .products-grid-header .products-grid-header-item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .products-grid-header li:not(.active-items) {
    display: none;
  }
  .products-grid-header .active-items {
    order: -1;
  }
  #burger-icon {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products-grid-header" id="products-header">

  <li class="products-grid-header-item active-items">
    <a class="" href="#products-header">1</a>
    <img id="burger-icon" src="image/icons/arrow-up-01-5122.png" alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="products-grid-header-item">
    <a class="" href="#products-header">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="products-grid-header-item">
    <a class="" href="#products-header">3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="products-grid-header-item">
    <a class="" href="#products-header">4</a>
  </li>
  <li class="products-grid-header-item">
    <a class="" href="#products-header">5</a>
  </li>
  <li class="products-grid-header-item">
    <a class="" href="#products-header">6</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var w = window.innerWidth;
if (w < 768) {
 $('.products-grid-header-item').on('click', function() {
         $('.products-grid-header-item').toggle();
         $('.products-grid-header li.active-items').removeClass('active-items');
         $(this).show();
         $(this).addClass('active-items');
     });
};

window.onresize = function ()
{
    if (w < 768) {
 $('.products-grid-header-item').on('click', function() {
         $('.products-grid-header-item').toggle();
         $('.products-grid-header li.active-items').removeClass('active-items');
         $(this).show();
         $(this).addClass('active-items');
     });
};
}
```

```css
.products-grid-header li{
 display: flex;
}
.products-grid-header{
 display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .products-grid-header{
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
  .products-grid-header .products-grid-header-item{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
 }
  .products-grid-header li:not(.active-items){
  display: none;
 }
  .products-grid-header .active-items{
  order: -1;
 }
  #burger-icon{
  display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products-grid-header" id="products-header">
                        
                        <li class="products-grid-header-item active-items">
                            <a class="" href="#products-header">1</a>
                            <img id="burger-icon" src="image/icons/arrow-up-01-5122.png" alt="">
                        </li>
                        <li class="products-grid-header-item">
                            <a class="" href="#products-header">2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="products-grid-header-item">
                            <a class="" href="#products-header">3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="products-grid-header-item">
                            <a class="" href="#products-header">4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="products-grid-header-item">
                            <a class="" href="#products-header">5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="products-grid-header-item">
                            <a class="" href="#products-header">6</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Не работает, если ширина экрана изменяется, то есть если уменьшать ее до 768, скрипт после этого не срабатывает. Работает только в том случае, если ширина изначально была 768 и менее.

Comment: Хорошо, минут через допишу код

Comment: Теперь как только меняется размер окна,проверяет и отрабатывает скрипт